# One or More Activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm fairly new to Android Programming and have a question about best practice regarding how many Activities I should create.

I'm working on a Puzzle App. Currently, I have a Single Activity and around 15 Fragments(SherlockFragment).

One problem I'm experiencing is that the Activity code is becoming large and complex. Another challenge is communication between fragments.

I understand that the best practice for communication between Fragments is to create an Interface in the fragments and implement the interface in the Activity.

ref: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Example:
I have a Contact fragment which contains a ListView where the user can select one or more contacts(Phone Contacts). By following the guidelines given by the link above, I could implement something like this in the Contact Fragment:

```
public interface OnContactSelected{
   public void onContactSelected(Contact contact);
}
...
...

mCallback.onContactSelected(contact);
```

Then, I can listen to the selection of contacts in the Activity using code like this:

```
public Class PuzzleActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
                    implements ContactFragment.OnContactSelected{
...
...
public void onActivityCreated(Contact contact){
   // Do something
}
```

The problem I'm facing is this:

The Contact fragment is an independent module used for different tasks, example:

1) Selecting a contact to add as a Friend

2) Selecting an opponent for an online game.

So the onContactSelected implementation in the Activity depends what I'm doing right now

```
public void onActivityCreated(Contact contact){
   // if{inInAddFriendMode())doThis(); else doThat();       
}
```

What I'm considering is to refactor the code and implement one activity for each of the main tasks in the APP, example:

- FriendActivity.java ( To show and add friends)
- MultiplayerGameSetupActivity.java (To configure a new game with how many players, choice of opponents, level of difficulty etc)
- GameActivity.java (The game it's self)
- SettingActivity.java

I'm also thinking about creating a base Activity which all of the Activities above extends.

To me this seems to solve all the problems by making the Activity code less complex, and also by allowing me to implement the Fragment interfaces cleanly in the Activities.

From your experience, is this a good approach, or should I stick to one Activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think it sounds like a good idea. I have found myself in the same situation as you a few times and maintaining it that way just gets more and more difficult with every addition.

The first thing I do now when I start a new project is create a Base Activity and a Base Fragment that all my others extend. I find doing it this way really helps with keeping it [**DRY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and since everything is separated MUCH easier to maintain.